# Trouble inserting code in a flash notice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a flash notice in a controller. The notice includes a `mail_to` helper method. I couldn't get the helper to work however without placing `view_context` before it. It now works but in my browser it outputs the html tags as a string instead of processing the html.

In other words, in my controller I have:

```
flash[:notice] = "blabla #{view_context.mail_to Setting::EMAIL} blabla."
```

but when this gets called i see this in the browser's flash notice:

```
blabla <a href="mailto:me@example.com">me@example.com</a> blabla
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Flash notices are intended for text use so it isn't escaping the code.  You could try using .html_safe or similar.

Comment: Cheers! Worked well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.e. change it to:

```
flash[:notice] = "blabla #{view_context.mail_to Setting::EMAIL} blabla.".html_safe
```

Comment: I'm curious, which Rails version are you using? [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596460/alex0112) seems to imply this won't work for 4.1+, and I'd love to know if you or @DevDude have any insight on how to accomplish this for those versions.